# Is it possible to partition a topological space into nonempty disjoint closed subsets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space containing at least 2 elements. Is it true, in general, that there exist 2 disjoint closed nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, such that $$X = A \cup B?$$ 
Is it false, in general?

Comment: Definitely no: connected spaces not only exist, but they are quite important.

Comment: This question is not at all obvious, if you are just considering the abstract definition of a topological space. But if you consider the example of the real numbers with the ordinary (metric) topology, you intuition should take you to the correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is true if and only if $X$ is not [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space).

Comment: Actually, it _is_ basically the definition of (non-)connectedness :-)